# Passing an object of a class to another class

Tags: c++, class, object, pass-by-reference

I have a class `Dictionary` which has a vector of strings in the Dictionary.
I am taking a `Word` from user and check if the word is in `Dictionary`.

Because of constraints of implementation, I need to pass an object of class `Dictionary` (variable `Lexicon`) to `Word` class (in a `Word` class I need to use a search function which is defined in `Dictionary` class).

So I am in the `Word` class and calling `MyWords.search();`.  But my code does not compile ! Why ?

```
int main()
{
Dictionary Lexicon(dictionary_file)
dictionary_file.close();
cout<<"Please enter a word to be searched in the dictionary:"<<endl;
cin>>word_to_search;


Word Keyword;
Keyword.setter(word_to_search);
Keyword.gettingDictionary(Lexicon);
return 0;
}

void Word::gettingDictionary(const Dictionary& myWords)
{
    myWords.search(keyword);// function defined in Dictionary class
                           //keyword is a member of Word class
}
```

Here the errors I receive when trying to compile :

```
 ++ -c main.cpp
In file included from dictionary.h:22:0,
                 from main.cpp:19:
 word.h:45:31: error: ‘Dictionary’ does not name a type
  void gettingDictionary(const Dictionary& myWords);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:82:41: error: no matching function for call to     ‘Word::gettingDictionary(Dictionary&)’
        Keyword.gettingDictionary(Lexicon);
                                     ^
 In file included from dictionary.h:22:0,
                 from main.cpp:19:
word.h:45:7: note: candidate: void Word::gettingDictionary(const int&)
 void gettingDictionary(const Dictionary& myWords);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
word.h:45:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from     ‘Dictionary’ to ‘const int&’
 make: *** [Makefile:7: main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Your code [does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your error please .

Comment: Dear user.  Human language has some syntax rules as well.  Every statement needs to be ended by a `.` (same principle as `;` in c++).  Without your the `.` your question was very difficult to understand. I edited accordingly.  Also keep in mind that "does not work" is useless.  "Does not compile" makes things much clearer ;-).

Comment: A class doesn't do anything, and is not callable. So "pass to a class" is not immediately meaningful.

Comment: Possibly of interest: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration . You would need one of those in `word.h`

Answer (score 0):

You have provided us some extracts of the cpp code.

Your error is somewhere else however.  The compiler claims that in line 45 of the file **word.h** (so in the header) there is a syntax error.  More precisely, the compiler claims that he doesn't know `Dictionary` there.

This error is probably related to the order in which you include the headers or define the classes.  If you can't define `Dictionary` before you define `Word` (which needs the Dictionary in the signature of the function),  you need to make a forward declare just before the `Word` class:

```
class Dictionary;    // to be defined afterwards
```

This leaves you the opportunity in the `Word` class to use `Dictionary` references and pointers in the member variables or in the signatures of member functions, even before that class is actually defined.  But of course, you'd need the real definition of the Dictionary class before implementing any of the Word members that use it.